# C: Need to write certain parts of a two-dimensional array to a new two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

So, I'm recursively calculating the determinant of a variable size array. So, if you're familiar with how to calculate determinants, here's a picture that displays what I'm doing:

I can't post an image because I don't have enough rep. Here's a link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIW1D.png

So, the part that is getting me extremely confused is making the smaller, 2x2 matrixes. (Keep in mind I'm coding this to work for any size of an array, not just 3x3).

So I'm not really asking how to compute the determinant, just how I can take the 3x3 array shown above, and only access the parts shown.

Comment: What are you doing currently? Is there something in your code that doesn't seem to work as you expected? You'll get significantly more interest in your if you post your code rather than just tell us about it.

Comment: Did _any_ of the work below help you in any way?  No comments or clarifications?

Answer (score 1):

So to calculate the determinant of a NxN matrix, you need to strike out the first row, then strike out columns one by one, and calculate determinants of the resulting bunch of (N-1)x(N-1) matrices. And to calculate those determinants, you need to strike the first row of the smaller matrices (which would be the *second* row of the original matrix) and then strike out additional columns one by one, and so on.

So it's easy to figure out what to do with the rows at each recursion level: at level 0 you go through row 0, at level 1 you go through level 1 and so on.

But columns are more involved. If at level 0 you strike out row 7, and at level 1 you strike out row 12 of the *current* matrix (which would be row 13 of the *original* matrix) and at level 2 you strike out row 10 of the *current* matrix, which is also row 10 of the matrix *one level up*, which is row 11 of the matrix *two levels up*, which is the original matrix... it would be pretty hard to determine which column of the original matrix to access at the lower levels of recursion.

It is possible of course to copy the entire matrix, sans the column that should be striken out, and pass the copy down the recursion level. But that would be rather wasteful.

It is more elegant to strike out column *numbers* instead of columns themselves. To achieve that, we create an one-dimensional array of column numbers. Initially it should contain numbers 0..(N-1) in order. As you prepare to compute each submatrix determinant, you copy that array, remove one column index from the copy, and pass it down the recursive computation.

So your recursive function would look approximately like this (in pseudocode)

```
float recursive_determinant (int N, float[N][N] matrix, 
                             int[N] column_array, int level)

    if level == N-1
      return matrix[level][column_array[0]]

    result = 0
    for each i in 0 .. N - level
       copy_of_column_array = column_array
       copy_of_column_array.remove_element(i)
       subdeterminant = recursive_determinant (N, matrix, 
                                               copy_of_column_array, level+1)
       result = result + subdeterminant * 
                         matrix[level][column_array[i]] * (-1)^(i+1)
    return result


 float determinant (int N, float[N][N] matrix)
     result = recursive_determinant (N, matrix, {0, 1, ..., N-1}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, what you have is a 2D array with 3x3 elements and you want to make calculations with certain elements of that 2D array. Your 2D array is declared as `int firstarray[xsize][ysize]`. Of course if it is xsize, ysize or ysize, xsize depends on how you prefer using it. in this specific case you give it would be `int firstarray[3][3]`.

Then you can access the smaller arrays by getting the appropriate elements of firstarray.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of arrays dynamically allocated, 1, 2, 3 and 4 dimensional:

```
int * Create1D(int r)
    {   
        int *space; 
        int *arr;

        space = calloc(r*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        arr   = calloc(sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        arr = (int *)space;

        return arr;
    }

    int ** Create2D(int c, int r)
    {   
        int *space; 
        int **arr;
        int    y;

        space   = calloc(c*r*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        arr   = calloc(c * sizeof(int *), sizeof(int));
        for(y=0;y<c;y++)
        {
            arr[y] = (int *)space + (y*r);   
        }
        return arr;
    }

    int *** Create3D(int p, int c, int r) 
    {
        int *space;
        int ***arr;
        int    x,y;

        space = calloc (p*c*r*sizeof(int),sizeof(int));
        arr = calloc(p * sizeof(int **), sizeof(int));
        for(x = 0; x < p; x++)
        {
            arr[x] = calloc(c * sizeof(int *),sizeof(int));
            for(y = 0; y < c; y++)
            {
                arr[x][y] = ((int *)space + (x*(c*r) + y*r));
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    int **** Create4D(int hR, int p, int c, int r)     
    {
        int *space;
        int ****arr;
        int    w,x,y;

        space = calloc(hR*p*c*r*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        arr = calloc(hR * sizeof(int ***), sizeof(int));
        for(w=0;w<hR;w++)
        {
            arr[w] = calloc(p * sizeof(int **), sizeof(int));
            for(x=0;x<p;x++)
            {
                arr[w][x] = calloc(c * sizeof(int *), sizeof(int));
                for(y=0;y<c;y++)
                {                                        
                    arr[w][x][y] = ((int *)space + (w*(p*c*r) + x*(c*r) + y*r)); 
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

This approach can be expanded to as many dimensions you would like.  Don't forget the free statements when you are done.